# Mixed Model Logistic Regression, max 2 observations per group

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am working with twin data with my exposure variable being inflammatory marker level (continuous) and outcome being disease status (binary). In order to account for twin relatedness, I was trying to use a mixed effects logistic regression similar to: `glmer(disease ~ x+(1|Family_No)` in the `lme4` package. But I have run into an issue regarding "boundary (singular) fit".

After doing a bit of searching, I saw it was recommended that I run a Bayesian model instead so I attempted to run `stanglmer` in the `rstanarm` package. I received warnings of Bulk Effective Samples Size (ESS) being too low as well as divergent transitions.

Based on my minimal understanding, I interpret this to be attributable to the fact that I have only one observation per twin for a total of 1050 observations but 820 families represented. This means that I have 820 groups, with the vast majority of them only having a single observation and the rest having two. I have previously been able to successfully run `glmer` with the exact above regression in the full dataset with approximately 2500 twins and 1000 families/groups.

A few questions:

1. How bad is it to have boundary/singular fit errors/warnings?
2. Did I correctly interpret the warning?
3. Can I continue pursuing a mixed effects logistic regression, given this warning?
4. Even if I can, should I? Do I have alternative methods to account for family relatedness in my sample?

Comment: Is `Family_No` supposed to be a unique identifier for each family? As in you have 820 families labeled Family 1 to Family 820, each with either 1 or 2 children?

Comment: My guess is that you get the warning because the data doesn't support estimating the random intercept, i.e. families do not differ from each other in terms of the average level of the outcome in this subset of your data (but they do in your full dataset). Is your random intercept in the output about zero? In that case you can probably just run a single-level glm, or a single-level glm with clustered standard errors.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Sointu Ah, that is something I did not consider. So I am currently running an agnostic proteomics analysis in 74 proteins. It looks like my random intercept in for some of the proteins is approximately 0 (~0.004), but for others, they range up to 0.71. Would it be acceptable to run single-level glm for the proteins with random intercepts of approx. 0 but then mixed glm for the proteins with intercepts that are greater?

Comment: @jamberhee, yes, in my opinion you can run a single-level glm if random intercept is essentially zero, and use mixed glm for the proteins for which it is non-zero. Also, you can consider clustering standard errors in your single-level glms, see https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/05/clustered-standard-errors-with-r/ which is an alternative to multilevel models that is often applied in situations like yours.